# Find wordpress user meta ID

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity

I wamt to make an auto fill field with gravity form that fill the name of the user and their roles automatically by inserting meta ID, for the name i found the ID 'display_name' but I can;t figure it out what is the roles meta ID, thank you.

Comment: Which meta ID you want to use? You want to get the user role ID?

Answer (score 0):

It is not so straightforward. user_meta table in wordpress database contains field wp_capabilities, in which is stored an object of capabilities. It is better to use WordPress funcions to extract user roles:

```
$id = ... // ID of the user
$caps = get_userdata(1)->wp_capabilities; // object of capabilites looking like {administrator: true}
$roles = array_keys($caps); // now we have list of capabilies in array
```